# GWT : Get file upload speed to display progress bar

Tags: gwt

I have a written a Servlet for uploading the file. On the UI, I want to display a progress bar for the file upload in GWT. How to get file upload speed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do it without relying on some server-side helper with "server push" is to send the form or file using `XMLHttpRequest` and using its progress events (supported basically [everywhere but IE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2), so you'd need to fallback to a basic form in IE). To do that with GWT, you have to use JSNI though.

If you absolutely need to support IE (and by that I mean display upload progress, because you could easily degrade gracefully to a standard form upload), you'd need the server to tell the client about the progress; that means you need a back-channel with "server push". The easiest is to use [GWTUpload](https://github.com/manolo/gwtupload) then or some similar third-party library.

For display, you can use a [`<progress>` element](http://caniuse.com/#feat=progress). In GWT, the easiest is to use it through UiBinder within an `HTMLPanel`: bind it to an `Element` `@UiField` and modify its properties with [`setPropertyDouble`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Element.html#setPropertyDouble(java.lang.String,%20double)) et al. It's relatively easy to create a `Widget` around a progress element created through [`Document.get().createElement("progress")`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Document.html#createElement(java.lang.String)). Or you can use a third-party library (GWT-Bootstrap or else) or create a progress bar out of `<div>` elements and CSS. Again, it depends which browsers you want/need to support.